# Have Svelte add the style inside a shadow dom

Tags: svelte, shadow-dom

My svelte app is supposed to render inside a shadow element. This works, but all the styles are added to the head of the outer document. I've tried creating an HTML element in the shadow dom, but the styles are still added to the head of the outer document.

Is there any way to tell Svelte where to add the styles? Having the styles in an external file is not an option in my use case.

The image shows the style in the outer head and no style within the shadow-root.

[image: A view of the DOM]

### Work-Around

As a work-around I know add a listener to the document-head and move what gets added to the shadow-root. This works in my application where there's only one shadow-dom at the time, but it's not a generic solution.

```js
const outerHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false }
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
     mutation.addedNodes.forEach(n => shadowHtml.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(n))
     })
}
const headObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);
headObserver.observe(outerHead, config);
```

Comment: Can you make Svelte create an ``open`` shadowRoot? You can then move it yourself (client-side)

Comment: You can't have stylesheets in shadow DOM in every browser today (or a few months ago, last time I checked). So you need to add a style string via JS. Also, I've tried using a "normal" (as opposed to CustomElement build) Svelte app in a shadow DOM, and it kind of worked. But in fact not totally. Transitions were broken, for example. Definitely not something I'd recommend, currently :-/

Comment: If I manually copy the styles from the outer head to the shadow DOM the style looks right. So if I could tell svelte where to add the styles, things would work. With an open shadow DOM I might move them once they are added. But this seems like quite a complicated work around.

Comment: You might be interested by that template https://github.com/stefanonepa/svelte-component-ts It is a hack, but it allows you to wrapp a svelte app into a Customelement with the styles embeded and transitions from svelte...